# Calculate $\int e^{2x}(\cos x)^3 dx$

Tags: real-analysis

> Calculate $$\int e^{2x}(\cos x)^3 dx$$

**My try:**

- Firsty I tried to use integration by parts but then I got:
  $$\int e^{2x}\cos^3(x) dx=...=\frac{1}{2}\cos^3(x) e^{2x}+\frac{3}{2}\left(\int e^{2x} \sin(x) dx-\int e^{2x} \sin^3(x) dx \right)$$So my calculation have not many sens because I have $\int e^{2x} (\sin x)^3 dx $ so I returned to similar problem how in the task.
- After that I tried to use integration by substitution:
  $$u=\cos(x)$$
  $$du=-\sin(x)dx$$
  However in this way I don't know how to transform $e^{2x}$ depending on the $u$.

  Have you any idea how to do this task?

Comment: Do it again. Then you'll get something that looks like your original integral, and you can rearrange to get an answer. So, e.g. $$\int e^{2x}\cos^3 x = A - B\int e^{2x} sin^3 x = A - B(C - D\int e^{2x} \cos^3 x)\\(1-BD)\int e^{2x}\cos^3 x = A-BC\\\int e^{2x}\cos^3 x = \frac{A-BC}{1-BD}$$ (Hopefully $BD\ne 1$ ... otherwise this method will be useless)

Comment: Perhaps you could expand $\cos t = {1 \over 2} (e^{it} + e^{-it})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\cos^3 x = \dfrac{1}{4}\left(\cos(3x)+3\cos x\right)$$

Plugging in gives:

$$\int e^{2x}\cos^3 x dx = \dfrac{1}{4}\int e^{2x}\cos(3x)dx + \dfrac{3}{4}\int e^{2x}\cos x dx$$

Looking at the first integral and performing IBP twice:

$$\int e^{2x}\cos(3x)dx = \dfrac{2}{13}e^{2x}\cos(3x)+\dfrac{3}{13}e^{2x}\sin(3x)$$

Then, the second integral and performing IBP twice:

$$\int e^{2x}\cos x dx = \dfrac{2}{5}e^{2x}\cos x + \dfrac{1}{5}e^{2x}\sin x$$

So, returning to the initial problem:

$$\int e^{2x}\cos^3 x dx = e^{2x}\left(\dfrac{1}{26}\cos(3x)+\dfrac{3}{52}\sin(3x) + \dfrac{3}{10}\cos x + \dfrac{3}{20}\sin x\right)+C$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know: why have you got $\int e^{2x}\cos(3x)dx = \dfrac{2}{13}e^{2x}\cos(3x)+\dfrac{3}{13}e^{2x}\sin(3x)$?

Comment: $$u = e^{2x}, du = 2e^{2x}dx, dv = \cos (3x)dx, v = \dfrac{1}{3}\sin(3x)$$ so after IBP once: $$\int e^{2x}\cos(3x) = \dfrac{1}{3}e^{2x}\sin(3x)-\dfrac{2}{3} \int e^{2x}\sin(3x)dx$$ Now, we apply IBP again: $$u=e^{2x}, du = 2e^{2x}dx,dv = \sin(3x)dx, v = -\dfrac{1}{3}\cos (3x)$$ So, after two steps: $$\int e^{2x}\cos(3x) = \dfrac{1}{3}e^{2x}\sin(3x) +\dfrac{2}{9}e^{2x}\cos(3x)-\dfrac{4}{9}\int e^{2x}\cos(3x)dx$$ Add $\displaystyle \dfrac{4}{9} \int e^{2x}\cos(3x)dx$ to both sides and multiply both sides by $\dfrac{9}{13}$ to get the result.

Comment: Oh thanks, really good idea!

Answer (score 3):

Linearise $\cos^3 x$ first: $\;\cos 3x=4\cos^3x-3\cos x$, so $\;\cos^3x=\frac14(\cos 3x+3\cos x)$, whence
$$\mathrm e^{2x}\cos ^3 x=\tfrac14\operatorname{Re}\Bigl(\mathrm e^{(2+3i)x}+3\mathrm e^{(2+i)x}\Bigl)$$
so calculate $\;\frac14\displaystyle\int\bigl(\mathrm e^{(2+3i)x}+3\mathrm e^{(2+i)x}\bigl) \mathrm dx$ and take its real part.